# Writing messages with Spring JmsTemplate using a TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, oracle-aq, spring-jms

Using Spring-JMS it is possible to receive messages within an external transaction context via the [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html).

However the only documented way to *write* a message is via `JmsTemplate.send(…)` and I can't see how this can be coerced to use a given `TransactionManager`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

More info: Ensuring a transaction manager is available (`WebSphereUowTransactionManager`), using `JmsTemplate.write` against an Oracle `AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(dataSource)` results in:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is oracle.jms.AQjmsException: could not use local transaction commit in a global transaction
  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:534)
Caused by: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: could not use local transaction commit in a global transaction
  at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.commitNoCheck(AQjmsSession.java:1053)
  at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.commit(AQjmsSession.java:1021)
  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(JmsUtils.java:217)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:573)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:536)
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466)
  ... 24 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: could not use local transaction commit in a global transaction
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.disallowGlobalTxnMode(PhysicalConnection.java:6647)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3635)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3680)
  at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.commit(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:133)
  at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.commitNoCheck(AQjmsSession.java:1049)
  ... 29 more
```

So whilst I have no reason to doubt the advise below, I am not able to test it as I can't figure out how to get AQ JMS to not attempt a commit. Will update as I learn more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that JMS producers are *inherently* transacted via JTA.  By sending a message via  JMS `MessageProducer`, the thread-local JTA transaction is used (if one is present).

This is hinting at by the Spring manual ([section 21.2.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jms.html#jms-tx)):

> `JmsTemplate` can also be used with the `JtaTransactionManager` and an XA-capable JMS `ConnectionFactory` for performing distributed transactions. Note that this requires the use of a JTA transaction manager as well as a properly XA-configured `ConnectionFactory`.

This is also suggested by `JmsAccessor.setSessionTransacted` (the superclass of `JmsTemplate`) ([javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/JmsAccessor.html#setSessionTransacted(boolean))):

> Set the transaction mode that is used when creating a JMS Session. Default is "false".
>   **Note that within a JTA transaction, the parameters passed to `create(Queue/Topic)Session(boolean transacted, int acknowledgeMode)` method are not taken into account. Depending on the J2EE transaction context, the container makes its own decisions on these values.** Analogously, these parameters are not taken into account within a locally managed transaction either, since the accessor operates on an existing JMS Session in this case.
>
> Setting this flag to "true" will use a short local JMS transaction when running outside of a managed transaction, and a synchronized local JMS transaction in case of a managed transaction (other than an XA transaction) being present. The latter has the effect of a local JMS transaction being managed alongside the main transaction (which might be a native JDBC transaction), with the JMS transaction committing right after the main transaction.

So by start a JTA transaction (i.e. by using Spring's transaction API with `JtaTransactionManager`) and calling `JmsTemplate.send(...)`, you will be sending the message bound to that transaction.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder, will Spring be able to find the transaction in flight when it is started by another non-Spring process? I'll find out tomorrow…

Comment: @Synesso: Yes, it will.  JTA transactions are managed by the container, not by Spring.