# Can JMS to configure to allow one message to receive/process by only one receiver?

Tags: spring, transactions, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am not sure if the issue is related to synchronization or more like transaction management, but my current goal is to implement a module by Spring like this:

1. One sender to send messages to queue
2. Multiple receivers to receive messages from queue.
3. Each receiver extracts information from the message and put into data persistence(database)
4. ***The most important requirement is ONLY ONE MESSAGE can be received by ONE receiver at a time so that it will not cause database transaction issue(like Optimistic Locking issue). If all receivers start to process the same message then it will cause trouble in the database transaction management.

The key is make sure to prevent a message to receive by more than one receiver, that's all.

I have finished 1,2,3 but confuse about 4, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974601/writing-messages-with-spring-jmstemplate-using-a-transactionmanager+) thread helpful, but I am not sure it can resolve above situation, also at same time I wonder if without JTA transaction management from Spring, can standard JMS or JMS provider(ActiveMQ, Websphere MQ, JBoss HonetQ etc) provide any configuration so that can guarantee one message can only be received or process by only one receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way JMS works. Only one consumer will get each message as long as you use a queue and not a topic.

Comment: Thanks Gary. And in such situation is XA/JTA a must if all receivers persist message data into the same database?

Comment: See [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) for alternatives to XA. To avoid XA, the use of the 'Best Effort 1PC` pattern is often used, as long as you can live with (or detect) occasional, rare, redeliveries of messages that have completed JDBC transactions. The JMS commit is done by Spring right after the JDBC commit so the only way a failure can occur is due to infrastructure, not code, but the possibility is > 0.

Comment: Thanks again. What if the sender is running on `JmsTemplate` with `sessionTransected=true` and `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`, then if the receiver is a POJO MDB with `@Transactional` annotated to onMessage() method and referred by `DMLC`, I am thinking it is a two phrase commitment pattern? I mean once if an exception is thrown within the `onMessage` method then I guess the whole JMS transaction is callbacked right?

Comment: Again; this implements a best effort 1PC; the JDBC tx will be committed followed by the JMS if possible. But yes, if an exception is thrown, both will rollback. You need XA for 2PC.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html) . As Gary already mentioned, the message on queue are always received by single consumer irrespective of number subscribers. This is true with/without transactions.